# I'm coding steps for gradient descent, to find the updated w and b, and I am having issues with my Python code

Tags: python, debugging, machine-learning, gradient-descent

The formula I am using to find the updated w and b parameters:

```
For w:
new w = w_current - learning rate * partial derivative with respect to w

For b: 
new b = b_current - learning rate * partial derivative with respect to b
```

From the picture I am calculating the partial derivatives with the variables tot_w and tot_b for each x and y, and storing the total in pd_w and pd_b.

Comment: shouldn't it be `tot_w = -2*(i*(j-b_current..))`

Comment: Omg yea that was it thanks

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter is complaining that variable i is sued as function. In the tol_w statement, there’s probably missing a arithmetic operator between I and the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tot_w = -2*(i*(j-b_current..))`.

Comment: Could you edit this to include some detail that might be useful for future readers? Why is this the solution?